# HTML output instead of HTML code in textarea

Tags: html

I have tried contentEditable in div instead of text area but it didn't work for me. I have a textarea and it displays the html code instead of plain text ( rich text). Are there any editors which I can use that are supported by IE8. Let me know how to use those editors instead of textarea.

Comment: Google `javascript rich text editor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **jQuery** Text Editor

http://jqueryte.com/demos

Example:

```
<script>
    $("textarea").jqte();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove any endline between tags of textarea, it must be like : Your Text Here